# Optimize file system for parallel read for HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have slave 16TB drive, that need to run 6 spacemesh node which need each to read 512G folder (so total ~3TB data) at same time as fast as it can (atm its 230MB/s as read is sequential with 1 node)
each folder has 4GB part files and that is all what is on HDD
Ubuntu 22.04 is the OS
Now I am trying to format ext4 file system with block size of 50M to prevent HDD seeking all the time as read is done in parallel as I run 6 nodes and all will start to read at same time

What I need is for OS to force it read file in largest segment as it can before it seek (to prevent seek as match as possible), I can not tweak node to work one after other atm, and reploting is no option

So what I try to do would look as, read POS1 file block1 50MB, POS2 file block1 50MB, etc
I must say I have no idea on OS level will OS try to read block1 and block 2 at same time and make HDD seek in middle of block read

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: is the OS on the same drive? you'll never achieve what you want, since the OS needs to read/write data all the time, which will of course mean seeking even if you organise your data perfectly. Also, the title is a bit misleading, since there is no possible way to "parallel read" a single hard drive, as that suggests reading multiple locations at once.

Comment: have you considered a 1TB HDD for each of these "spacemesh" nodes? If your motherboard supports 7 SATA (1 for the OS drive, one for each of the spacemesh drives) then it could work better

Comment: OS is on nvme so no issue there
I have those drives, no in mood to buy 1TB ones

my plan is to test formating HDD with block size of 50MB 
sudo mkfs.ext4 -b 50M /dev/sdb
and see will that force kernel to read only in 50MB chunks, but that all need a lot time to setup and test each config

Comment: My question is if you want "at same time as fast as it can"  nvme will obviously beat 230mb/s no problem not even a fair race.  You can use 2+ HDD and RAID them if your sticking with HDD.  So ultimately, tweaking the OS **might** get you 10%, but nvme **will** get you 10x or better.  Is it not better to use a solution that will get 10x++ performance vs 10%?

Comment: @cybernard Use case is specific, I still need to test with block size, I just need file system settings that will make HDD seek from one file to other to minimum, as there are just 4TB of 4GB files that are read 2 time a month and that time need to be under 9h, and they are read by 6 nodes

Comment: So how close are you to 9h?  Defragmenting the file system periodically will give you some performance gains as all the files will be contiguous.  Also you can use partitioning to get better performance.  The basic concept is, the larger the circumference of the track on the HDD the more data it hold the faster it is.  So the outer most tracks are about 3" diameter because hdd are 3.5".  Pi *r^2 =circumference.  Therefore you want to partition the front of the hdd with larger circumferences in 1 partition and the others in another partition.

Comment: I already have all the data, in the start of HDD, frash copied as defregmen tool for linux all are worthless
Will report the tests here when they are done

Comment: Test with: mkfs.ext4 -C 64M -O bigalloc /dev/sdb1
6x process 6x 0.5TB ~3TB read at same time, took ~7 hours not bad, but I want to try XFS (block size can be larger) next or see if -C 256M can help....

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find solution, making large cluster for ext4 did not help at all but command to read ahead have:

```
blockdev --setra 65536000 /dev/sdc
```

Now I tested it and average speed with 7 nodes that read in same time was 200Mb/s which is gr8 as sequential read of 1 node was maxed at 230MB/s which is max speed of this HDD.